# Moving Through a Recordset evaluating current month plus two previous months

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am writing a VBA macro to manage a database for cell phones.  What I am testing for is that if any of the previous months (current month plus previous two months) have activity. If all three months show "no usage" then we will check a Boolean box true to then deactivate the line.

I have the logic written partially.

I started with a crosstab query that has calculated fields.  This way my query always maintains structure.  I am evaluated the fields for the value.  If the field value is great than zero, move on.  If it is equal to zero, then set a counter to 1.  Once the counter reaches three, mark the line's Boolean box as true for non-usage.

The code is listed below.  I have two columns before the columns of months on my table, therefore my rsIndexes start at 2 and go through 12 and the entire table has 14 columns.  With the For Next loop that I created I can manage the situation that occurs very naturally such as 7,6,5 (Jul, Jun, May).

Here's my issue: How do you use this structure and move through the recordset when you have to evaluate data with recordset indexes of 1, 12, 11 (Jan, Dec, Nov).  Is the movement from 1 back to 12 then to 11 that is my issue.

```
Sub detectNonUsage2()

Dim rsNonUsageList As New ADODB.Recordset

lastMonthIndex = [Forms]![frmNonUsageLogic]![cboCurMonth].ListIndex

lastMonthIndex = (lastMonthIndex + 2)

MsgBox lastMonthIndex

rsSQL = "Select * from qryDeviceIDbyMonth"

rsNonUsageList.Open rsSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

Do Until rsNonUsageList.EOF

    curVal = rsNonUsageList(lastMonthIndex)

    curMonth = rsNonUsageList(lastMonthIndex).Name
    curCount = 0

    For curField = lastMonthIndex To lastMonthIndex - 2 Step -1

           If rsNonUsageList(lastMonthIndex) = 0 Then
                curCount = curCount + 1
            Else

            End If

        curMonth = rsNonUsageList(curField).Name
        Debug.Print curMonth

    Next curField

        If curCount >= 3 Then
        'set flag for nonUsage
        Else

        End If

        rsNonUsageList.MoveNext

    Loop

    rsNonUsageList.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Throwing up a bunch of different database tags is not appreciated here.

Comment: All of those tags were automatically added except for one.

Comment: Another friendly hint:  Focus on what your question really is.  Submitting partially written logic along with a long explanation does not necessarily inspire help and may turn others away.  I realize that sometimes more detail is necessary, but probably not in this case.  It takes practice at formulating a great question.  I perceive that you simply want an efficient way of iterating through a "ring" of repeating numbers... like months of the year.  Is that it?

Comment: When I creating a post, I try to construct in such a way that gives enough detail without too much detail.  I wanted to show my efforts but also gleen the information others have to offer as I am new to programming and trying to learn from other.  One important piece that I just thought about and you mentioned is the evaluation of numbers within a single year for a single device.  If it was just evaluating Jan-Dec then going down the recordset, I would have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "use this structure" since your explanation and code was a bit hard to follow. If all you need is to iteration through numeric months of the year, an efficient solution will use **modular arithmetic**.  Consider the following expression:

```
result = ((month + delta + 11) mod 12) + 1
```

`result` will be the resultant month if shifting from the starting `month` by `delta` steps, e.g. +1 or -1.  This assumes `month` and `result` are in the set from 1 to 12.

An alternative is to simply use basic **if statements** to detect and control what happens when you're at the edge.  If moving forward then:

```
if month == 12 then result = 1 else result = month + 1
```

otherwise if moving backward

```
if month == 1 then result = 12 else result = month - 1
```

Comment: I get that the code is hard to follow as I am being mentored and a bit lost in the process myself.  When I say "use this structure" I am referring to the query that I set up to refer back to the RS.  Based upon your previous comment, it was that detail that was not necessary to get the question out there and probably muddied the water.  I will check out your code suggestion and let you know.  I did set up an IF THEN ELSE statement but it is the going from Jan to Dec within the same device ID that is still the issue because you only have 12 rs indexes for each month of the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple query like this:

```
Update 
    CellLines
Set 
    Deactivated = True
Where 
    PhoneId Not In 
        (Select Distinct PhoneId From CellCalls
        Where CallDate Between 
            DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 2, 1) And Date()
```